# param_need_backward, layer_need_backward_ and blob_need_backward_ in Caffe

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, caffe

My networks has layers `D->C1,R1,C11,R11->P1->C2,R2->loss`. D for data, C for Conv, R for Relu,and P for Pool.

I set C1, C2 with
lr_mult=0 and decay_mult=0.

Those layers I don't want backpropagation.

When I look at `param_need_backward, layer_need_backward_ and blob_need_backward_`  arrays in Net Init
(Net::Init(const NetParameter& in_param)

`param_need_backward` for C1 and C2 is false.

But `layer_need_backward_ and blob_need_backward_`  for C2 are true and `layer_need_backward_ and blob_need_backward_`  for C1 are false.

What it does is C2 layer still do back propagation, but it doesn't update it weights.
But for C1,back propagation skips this C1 layer at all.

Is my understanding correct?

`params_lr_` array has all `lr_mult` values. Where are these values used?

EDIT:

According to Conv_layer.cpp

```
if (this->param_propagate_down_[0] || propagate_down[i]) {
      for (int n = 0; n < this->num_; ++n) {
        // gradient w.r.t. weight. Note that we will accumulate diffs.
        if (this->param_propagate_down_[0]) {
          this->weight_cpu_gemm(bottom_data + n * this->bottom_dim_,
              top_diff + n * this->top_dim_, weight_diff);
        }
        // gradient w.r.t. bottom data, if necessary.
        if (propagate_down[i]) {
          this->backward_cpu_gemm(top_diff + n * this->top_dim_, weight,
              bottom_diff + n * this->bottom_dim_);
        }
      }
    }
```

param_propagate_down_[0] is flase if lr_mult=0 and weights are not updated.

But propagate_down[i] is true, so layer still propagate down.